# Sort DICT by Keys when they are DATETIME

Tags: python, sorting, datetime

I'm trying to sort a DICT by Keys, but the big issue i founded first the KEYS values is a 'STRING' based on quarterly period.

Follow a example:

```
ex_dict = {
    "6/2021": 1,
    "9/2020": 1,
    "6/2019": 1,
    "3/2020": 1,
    "6/2020": 1,
    "9/2019": 1,
    "3/2021": 1,
    "3/2019": 1,
}
```

I know i can used the function sorted(), to order the keys then use list comprehension to order with original values.

Something like this:

```
in: print({k: v for k, v in sorted(ex_dict.items())})

out: {
   '3/2019': 1,
   '3/2020': 1,
   '3/2021': 1,
   '6/2019': 1,
   '6/2020': 1,
   '6/2021': 1,
   '9/2019': 1,
   '9/2020': 1
}
```

But he only orders using the first number, how i can transform this keys to DATETIME to make order on the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```python
({k: v 
  for k, v in sorted(
      ex_dict.items(),
      key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x[0], "%d/%Y")
      )
})
```

Output:

```
{'3/2019': 1,
 '6/2019': 1,
 '9/2019': 1,
 '3/2020': 1,
 '6/2020': 1,
 '9/2020': 1,
 '3/2021': 1,
 '6/2021': 1}
```

1. [datetime.strptime()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#datetime.datetime.strptime)  class method creates a datetime object
   from a string representing a date and time and a corresponding
   format string.
2. Next sorted by date.

Comment: Thanks! Perfect solution!

Comment: @FelipeCid I'd guess that this one would be computationally expensive, compared to Brown Bear's answer, which just manipulates the strings. I'd use this one if performance is no issue, else I'd try the other one.

Comment: Add to dict:
ex_dict['12/2019']=1  
and try.
String sorting gets wrong order: {'12/2019': 1, '3/2019': 1, '6/2019': 1, '9/2019': 1, '3/2020': 1, '6/2020': 1, '9/2020': 1, '3/2021': 1, '6/2021': 1}

Answer (score 5):

you can use `key` option for example:

```
{k: v for k, v in sorted(
        ex_dict.items(), 
        key=lambda x: list(reversed(list(map(int, x[0].split('/')))))
    )
}
```

the output

```
{'3/2019': 1,
 '6/2019': 1,
 '9/2019': 1,
 '3/2020': 1,
 '6/2020': 1,
 '9/2020': 1,
 '3/2021': 1,
 '6/2021': 1}
```

read details here [key-functions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions)

Answer (score 2):

see below
(the idea is make a tuple that contains the date as string and a real date, sort it and populate an ordered dict)

```
from datetime import datetime
from collections import OrderedDict

ex_dict = {
    "6/2021": 1,
    "9/2020": 1,
    "6/2019": 1,
    "3/2020": 1,
    "6/2020": 1,
    "9/2019": 1,
    "3/2021": 1,
    "3/2019": 1,
}

temp = [(datetime(month=int(x[0]), year=int(x[2:]),day=1), x) for x in ex_dict.keys()]
temp = sorted(temp, key=lambda x: x[0])
data = OrderedDict()
for entry in temp:
    data[entry[1]] = ex_dict[entry[1]]
print(data)
```

output

```
OrderedDict([('3/2019', 1), ('6/2019', 1), ('9/2019', 1), ('3/2020', 1), ('6/2020', 1), ('9/2020', 1), ('3/2021', 1), ('6/2021', 1)])
```